# How to get data from sqlite, and show it using stackwidget?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to retrieve url image from sqlite, then convert it to bitmap and show it into stackwidget. When insert url image manually, one by one, it works well. But when i use url image from sqlite, application is force close and my stackwidget doesn't show image.

```
public class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

 ...

    StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        FilmHelper filmHelper = FilmHelper.getInstance(mContext);
        filmHelper.open();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase databases = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(databases, "note");

        ArrayList<Film> ini = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c =FilmHelper.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM note" , null );

        c.moveToFirst();

        Film note;
        int i;
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                for (i=0; i < count; i++  ) {
                    do {
                        note = new Film();
                        note.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_ID)));
                        note.setPosterPath(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(IMAGE)));
                        ini.add(note);
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/" +
                                    ini.get(i).getPosterPath());
                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
                            mWidgetItems.add(image);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                        c.moveToNext();
                    } while (!c.isAfterLast());
                }
            }
            c.close();
            databases.close();
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing network consuming task like converting url to bitmap inside forloop in main thread.
you can use Asynctask that will download bitmap from url to you in onPostExecute and from that you can add bitmap to mWidgetItems.

```
class ConvertUrltoBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
public Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    Bitmap map = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        map= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
    try {
        mWidgetItems.add(bitmap);
    }catch (Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```